# Are there any rule-based programming language that are not considered production systems?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, production, rules-engine

I am trying to learn the difference between a production system and a rule-based system because it seems to me that they are the same thing basically. I know that both refer to programs (system) that can create Artificial Intelligence Software and Expert Systems.

Can a production system be something else than a rule-based system (maybe a production system can be implemented in a different way) ?

Can a rule-based system (programming language) be something else than a production system ?

In computer science are rules and production the same thing? I think that when learning about grammars the professor used rule and production interchangeably.

Comment: I've looked at both wikipedia articles, and I don't see a material difference between these two terms.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So there is not difference between rule and production in the context of Computer Science ?

Comment: I didn't say that.  What I said is that I looked at the two Wikipedia articles that define these two terms, and based on the text contained in those two articles, I don't see any differences that would materially affect their interchangeability.  In other words, those two terms look like they're essentially the same to me.  That doesn't mean there aren't differences, but those differences don't seem significant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for the clarification.  However these two terms: rule and production seem to mean the same in more areas of Computer Science although in English language they mean very different things. How did this happen? Why did those two different terms ended up meaning the same thing ? Do you have any idea ? I asked this specific question here as it seemed a more fit sub http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67417/how-did-the-word-production-ended-up-being-a-synonym-with-the-word-rule-in-t  in case you want to check out the more detailed question.

Comment: Sometimes in compiler front-ends we refer to a production as the application of the (production) rules in the context of parsing specific input.  Thus, the production *rules* are static to the language and across all texts; whereas, sometimes the term *production* is used to describe dynamic applications of those rules to an input.  YMMV.

Comment: @yoyo_fun: Welcome to the English language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is fundamentally about a theoretical computer science problem, and not about the software development life cycle: “*Can a rule-based system be something else than a production system?*”